# How do I install a Wifi adapter on Linux Mint WITHOUT using Terminal?

Tags: linux, wifi

I'd been having this problem with every single PC I'd switched out (they had Linux). I'm new to Linux Mint, and I'm used to Windows desktop stuff. I'd come to the understanding that on Linux, you have to do more than just plug it in and go, and that's fine, but I've been running in circles trying to figure it out myself.

I tried using Terminal (having looked up certain codes to try to figure out what I'm doing), but it's like having to speaking a language I don't know, so I'd REALLY prefer not to go there.

So my question is: what's the installation process that I need to be aware of? Please be as detailed as possible, as I'm not technologically savvy.

Comment: You will need to say which wireless card your PC has, as that will affect the answer. However, broadly speaking, you either download the driver from a website and then click on it to install it, or you activate a driver from the System Settings in Mint.

Answer (score -1):

On the terminal type in the following commands (one line at a time)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

In the search bar look for your wireless driver.

If you don't want to do this trough terminal head over to
http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/synaptic and download it manually but you're going to have to unzip the download trough the command line. I recommend to do it trough terminal it's very straight forward and easier to download. just do the commands above.

Comment: Considering OP says "Linux Mint" and "without using terminal", I'd say you missed a couple of key points.

Comment: you're going to eventually have to use the terminal... you need to update your repos and unzip your downloads. I mean this is why linux is linux because you finally get to use your fingers. Also Synaptic Package Manager is a GUI tool you can simply download it trough the command or download it trough the website and unzip it which I find more complicated especially for new users.